# Debian /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lodbc

Tags: linux, debian

I am newbie in Linux, try to install PHP 5.6 on Debian 7, got this error, have no idea, also haven't found any solution on the internet, can some one support me pls.

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lodbc

thanks

Answer (score 2):

solved!

need to run this command:

apt-get install unixodbc-dev

thanks to this blog:

http://www.kcaran.com/entries/technology/linux/linuxodbc.html